# sequence of strings of letters in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, sequence

I have a data set (*GRE*) with about 40000 rows and 400 columns. I need to identify for each participant (*Subject*) and each trial (*Trial*) in column *LABEL* two sequences of strings: 1) *pret1* followed by *t1*, and 2) *pret2* followed by *t2*. The number of occurrences of *pret1*, *t1*, *pret2* and *t2* is not important.

What I would like to have is a new column in which I assign a value of 0 to the observations in which there is a sequence, 1 when there is no sequence, and NA for the observations/rows that cannot be assessed because they do not include any of *pret1*, *t1*, *pret2*, *t2*
Following a reproducible example.

```
LABEL <-c("vc","gfda","gsgs_pret2","sfgsgt_pret2","hhjcf_t2","xa_postt2","sgs","sgsd","fgnx_pret1","wqraffsd_pret1","zdgn_t1","with_postt1","nzf","great_postt2","l","fjs","ssmlk_t1","gjkgj_t1","djdj_postt1","ityufhj","eyhjjfjfhjf","dghjdj_pret2","gjkt_t2","kuutt_t2","truetye_postt2","fj","hgfg_pret1","zetytu") 
Subject <- rep(c(1,2), each=14)
Trial <- rep(1:4,each=7)
OUTPUT<-c("NA","NA","0","0","0","NA","NA","NA","0","0","0","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","1","1","NA","NA","NA","0","0","0","NA","NA","1","NA") 
GRE <- data.frame(LABEL,Subject,Trial,OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Can you also add the expected output as another column

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the suggestion. Output is now in the reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` (not necessary, just a preference for its syntax). It can almost certainly be simplified and made more readable, but at least it gives the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
res <-
  GRE %>% 
  group_by(Trial, Subject) %>% 
  mutate(
    pret1 = grepl("_pret1$", LABEL),
    t1 = grepl("_t1$", LABEL),
    pret2 = grepl("_pret2$", LABEL),
    t2 = grepl("_t2$", LABEL),
    seq_ = (any(pret1) & any(t1) & (pret1 | t1)) |
      (any(pret2) & any(t2) & (pret2 | t2)),
    no_seq_ = ((all(!pret1) | all(!t1)) & (pret1 | t1)) |
      ((all(!pret2) | all(!t2)) & (pret2 | t2)),
    OUTPUT_2 = ifelse(seq_, 0L, ifelse(no_seq_, 1L, NA_integer_))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() # %T>% print(n = 28)

# # A tibble: 28 × 11
#             LABEL Subject Trial OUTPUT pret1    t1 pret2    t2  seq_ no_seq_ OUTPUT_2
# <fctr>   <dbl> <int> <fctr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>    <int>
# 1              vc       1     1     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 2            gfda       1     1     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 3      gsgs_pret2       1     1      0 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 4    sfgsgt_pret2       1     1      0 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 5        hhjcf_t2       1     1      0 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 6       xa_postt2       1     1     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 7             sgs       1     1     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 8            sgsd       1     2     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 9      fgnx_pret1       1     2      0  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 10 wqraffsd_pret1       1     2      0  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 11        zdgn_t1       1     2      0 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 12    with_postt1       1     2     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 13            nzf       1     2     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 14   great_postt2       1     2     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 15              l       2     3     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 16            fjs       2     3     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 17       ssmlk_t1       2     3      1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    TRUE        1
# 18       gjkgj_t1       2     3      1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    TRUE        1
# 19    djdj_postt1       2     3     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 20        ityufhj       2     3     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 21    eyhjjfjfhjf       2     3     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 22   dghjdj_pret2       2     4      0 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 23        gjkt_t2       2     4      0 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 24       kuutt_t2       2     4      0 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   FALSE        0
# 25 truetye_postt2       2     4     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 26             fj       2     4     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA
# 27     hgfg_pret1       2     4      1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    TRUE        1
# 28         zetytu       2     4     NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE       NA

identical(as.integer(as.character(res$OUTPUT)), res$OUTPUT_2)
# [1] TRUE
# Warning message:
# In identical(as.integer(as.character(res$OUTPUT)), res$OUTPUT_2) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run the code an error appears: `Error: incompatible size (28), expecting 4 (the group size) or 1`, probably because of the last line of the code. How can I solve it?

Comment: Weird... Have you copy-pasted my code? Have you maybe replaced `LABEL` with `GRE$LABEL` or sth like that? What makes you think it's the last line?

Answer (score 0):

I have this code but my results is diferent from your example:

Identify which lables have the pattern

```
havePattern <- grep('_t1|_t2|pret1|pret2', GRE$LABEL)
```

Create new column

```
GRE$OUTPUT2 <- NA
```

Split the text and match with alphabet. If theres a sequence the function return 1, if not 0. Apply just for rows with the pattern

```
GRE$OUTPUT2[havePattern] <- sapply(GRE$LABEL[havePattern], function(x){
  str_sp <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
  numb <- na.omit(match(str_sp, letters))
  any(diff(numb) == 1) * 1
})

GRE
            LABEL Subject Trial OUTPUT OUTPUT2
1              vc       1     1     NA      NA
2            gfda       1     1     NA      NA
3      gsgs_pret2       1     1      0       0
4    sfgsgt_pret2       1     1      0       1
5        hhjcf_t2       1     1      0       0
6       xa_postt2       1     1     NA      NA
7             sgs       1     1     NA      NA
8            sgsd       1     2     NA      NA
9      fgnx_pret1       1     2      0       1
10 wqraffsd_pret1       1     2      0       1
11        zdgn_t1       1     2      0       0
12    with_postt1       1     2     NA      NA
13            nzf       1     2     NA      NA
14   great_postt2       1     2     NA      NA
15              l       2     3     NA      NA
16            fjs       2     3     NA      NA
17       ssmlk_t1       2     3      1       0
18       gjkgj_t1       2     3      1       1
19    djdj_postt1       2     3     NA      NA
20        ityufhj       2     3     NA      NA
21    eyhjjfjfhjf       2     3     NA      NA
22   dghjdj_pret2       2     4      0       1
23        gjkt_t2       2     4      0       1
24       kuutt_t2       2     4      0       0
25 truetye_postt2       2     4     NA      NA
26             fj       2     4     NA      NA
27     hgfg_pret1       2     4      1       1
28         zetytu       2     4     NA      NA
```